# SQL: Rank over Occurrence

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume a table like

```
PROD   |SIZE|..
-------|----|--
ProdA  |150 |..
ProdA  |200 |..
ProdA  |200 |..
ProdA  |200 |..
ProdB  |150 |..
ProdB  |150 |..
ProdB  |150 |..
ProdC  |200 |..
....   |... |..
```

I need a query to match the most occuring SIZE per Product, resulting in:

```
PROD   |SIZE|..
-------|----|--
ProdA  |200 |..
ProdB  |150 |..
```

I guess I have to use a sophisticated `rank() over(partition)` construct with some `count()` in it, but somehow I can't figure it out.

I stuck at

```sql
SELECT
  PROD
, SIZE
FROM (
  SELECT
    PROD
  , SIZE
  , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PROD ORDER BY COUNT(SIZE)) AS RANK
)
WHERE
  RANK = 1
```

*EDIT:* Added one more column to example to clarify there is more data..

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? You are getting an error message you didn't tell us, I suppose? Why have us guess? You forgot the FROM and GROUP BY clause and maybe you shouldn't use RANK as an alias. Then you forgot to order *descending*. Apart from that, your query looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle features the function `STATS_MODE` that returns the most frequent value:

```
select prod, stats_mode(size)
from mytable
group by prod;
```

In case of ties (i.e. two or more sizes sharing the highest frequency), you get one arbitrarily.

And here is the `RANK` query working even for ties. We use `RANK` to rank the aggregated records (i.e. product sizes) per product by frequency and only keep those best ranked sizes (rank #1).

```
select prod, size
from
(
  select 
    prod, 
    size,
    rank() over (partition by prod order by count(*) desc) as rnk
  from mytable
  group by prod, size
)
where rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for a good answer. The only thing which will go wrong in case of tie. Instead of RANK() we should use DENSE_RANK() to get accurate ranking.

Comment: @Avrajit Roy: No, rank #1 will be given to the same rows, no matter whether you use `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`.

Comment: Yeaah true. I was anticipating if user asks for more rank other thn first one :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one too. Hope it helps.

```
SELECT C.*
FROM
  (SELECT B.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B.CD ORDER BY B.RN DESC) RNK
  FROM
    (SELECT A.*,
      COUNT(A.QT) OVER(PARTITION BY A.CD,A.QT ORDER BY A.CD DESC) RN
    FROM
      (SELECT 1 AS CD, 200 QT FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS CD, 200 QT FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS CD, 200 QT FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS CD, 150 QT FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS CD, 100 QT FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS CD, 150 QT FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS CD, 100 QT FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS CD, 500 QT FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS CD, 100 QT FROM DUAL
      )A
    ) B
  )C
WHERE C.RNK = 1 ;
```